# Latest JxBrowser crashes on OSX

Tags: jxbrowser

One of our users is reporting a consistent JxBrowser crash on Mac OS X 10.12.6

They are using JxBrowser v6.17, the Oracle jre1.8.0_152 and the latest webdrivers.

The full crash log is available here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/4126

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

JxBrowser has two rendering modes: lightweight and heavyweight. In the heavyweight rendering mode we embed a native window into your Java application window and configure Chromium engine to render content into this native window using GPU. In order to embed the native window on Mac we have to initialize Chromium engine in Java process. JavaFX WebView is based on WebKit engine that is also initialized in Java process. The crash you see usually occurs when you mix both JxBrowser and JavaFX WebView in the same application. We do not recommend using JxBrowser in heavyweight mode and JavaFX WebView in the same application on Mac.

In case you have to use both JxBrowser and JavaFX WebView I recommend that you switch to the lightweight rendering mode in JxBrowser. To do that you need to start JxBrowser with the following VM parameter:

`-Djxbrowser.ipc.external=true`

This will force JxBrowser to initialize Chromium in a separate native process that will allow you to avoid conflicts between JxBrowser and WebView. It's not possible to use JxBrowser in the heavyweight rendering mode in this case.

If you need to use JxBrowser in heavyweight mode with JavaFX WebView in the same application you should make sure that the `BrowserCore.initialize()` method is invoked before creating any WebView instance.

Comment: Thanks, thats very useful to know.